# Why is instance variable nil in my rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model (agents) in my app who can create posts. They can do this from their dashboard. I also show all their existing posts within their dashboard. The problem comes when trying to create a new post with no content which I'm testing to make sure it renders an error. Creating a post with content works but creating one with out keeps triggering an error which says my @posts instance variable is nil. Not sure if I missed something?

Dashboard view:

```
.container
    .column.span9

      - if current_agent
        = render 'home/shared/agent_post_panel'
        = render 'home/shared/agent_dashboard_tabs'
```

agent_dashboard_tabs:

```
  .tabs-container
    #posts
      .content
        - if @posts.any? //This is where the error is triggered
          = render partial: 'shared/post', collection: @posts
```

Controller for Dashboard:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate!, only: [:dashboard]

  def index
  end

  def dashboard
    if current_agent
      @post  = current_agent.posts.build
      @posts = current_agent.posts
    end
  end
end
```

My post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_agent!


  def create
    @post = current_agent.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Post not created"
      render 'home/dashboard'
    end
  end

end
```

Tests:

```
feature 'Creating posts' do

  let(:agent) { FactoryGirl.create(:agent) }

  before do
    sign_in_as!(agent)
    visit dashboard_path
  end

  scenario "creating a post with valid content" do
    fill_in 'post_content', :with => 'I love donuts'
    expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
  end

  scenario "creating a post with invalid content" do
    expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Post, :count)
    click_button "Post"
    page.should have_content("Post not created")
    page.should have_content("can't be blank")
  end
```

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive question with tests :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering `home/dashboard` from within `posts#create` when the post has errors, but you are not setting `@posts` variable.

You should add this before `render 'home/dashboard'`

```
@posts = current_agent.posts
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, overlooked this completely. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect_to dashboard_path` instead of `render 'home/dashboard'`.
and you can keep flash message on dashboard by calling `keep` method of flash in `home#dashboard`.

```
flash.keep
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, You are having an issue in the loading the page (HomeController#index)

As I can see prior to load your index action, you check if the user is logged in or not,

make sure your application flow goes into

```
if current_agent
      #make sure you application flow comes here
      @post  = current_agent.posts.build
      @posts = current_agent.posts
end
```

If not you might want to slightly modify this flow as (if this fits your requirment)

```
if current_agent
          @post  = current_agent.posts.build
          @posts = current_agent.posts
else
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = []
end
```

and finally its always good to use `try`, when you are not sure about the object you get

```
if @posts.try(:any?)
```